# How do you sum up similiar values in a Python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python list with the following data:

```
['Tom', 'Smith', '1'] 
['Tom', 'Miller', '7'] 
['Tom', 'Smith', '2'] 
['Tom', 'Miller', '3']
```

I want to dedup and sum up similar values so the end result looks like this:

```
['Tom', 'Smith', '3'] 
['Tom', 'Miller', '10']
```

Being new to Python I'm stumped at how to proceed. My ugly solution involves creating a 2nd list and removing all items from the first list that match and adding it up and putting it in the new list. But I get lost somewhere in there on details. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Darkstarone, but I'd use a `defaultdict`, and make the key a `tuple`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['Tom', 'Smith', '1'],
        ['Tom', 'Miller', '7'],
        ['Tom', 'Smith', '2'],
        ['Tom', 'Miller', '3']]

output = defaultdict(int)
for datum in data:
    key = (datum[0], datum[1])
    output[key] += int(datum[2])
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention I wanted the end result to be a list also because I'm going to write it to a csv file. But from your solution I was able to convert the defaultdict to a list and I'm happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a `dict` structure:

```
data = [['Tom', 'Smith', '1'], 
['Tom', 'Miller', '7'], 
['Tom', 'Smith', '2'], 
['Tom', 'Miller', '3']]

results = {}

for l in data:
    name = l[0] + " " + l[1]
    if name in results:
        results[name] += int(l[2])
    else:
        results[name] = int(l[2])

# Results: {'Tom Miller': 10, 'Tom Smith': 3}
```

If you want to maintain order of the names (normal dicts don't do this) you could use an `OrderedDict`:

```
import collections

data = [['Tom', 'Smith', '1'], 
['Tom', 'Miller', '7'], 
['Tom', 'Smith', '2'], 
['Tom', 'Miller', '3']]

results = collections.OrderedDict()

for l in data:
    name = l[0] + " " + l[1]
    if name in results:
        results[name] += int(l[2])
    else:
        results[name] = int(l[2])
```

And if you need the result to be in the same list format at the end (add this after making the dict):

```
results_list = []
for k,v in results.iteritems():
    group = []
    group.extend(k.split())
    group.append(str(v))
    results_list.append(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this would be with the pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [['Tom', 'Smith', '1'], ['Tom', 'Miller', '7'], ['Tom', 'Smith', '2'], ['Tom', 'Miller', '3']]})

df['name'] = ['{0} {1}'.format(x, y) for x, y in list(zip([x[0] for x in df['col']], [x[1] for x in df['col']]))]
df['val'] = [int(x[2]) for x in df['col']]

df.groupby('name')['val'].agg(np.sum)
```

Returns:

```
Tom Miller    10
Tom Smith      3
Name: val, dtype: int64
```